# bash - Don't propagate signal to child processes

Tags: bash, shell

I have this simple bash script that responds to `SIGUSR{1,2}`, while running a GUI program in the background:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'echo trapping && sleep inf' USR1 USR2
echo $$
gnome-calculator &>/dev/null &
sleep inf
```

(feel free to replace `gnome-calculator` with any other GUI programs)

I then ran `kill -USR1` with the PID that the script printed, and the script correctly echoed `"trapping"` in response. But unfortunately, `gnome-calculator` was killed in the process.

Is there a way to make it so that the signal does not get propagated to its child processes? It looks like that you can do something like `trap '' USR1 USR2`, but I want to actually do something in response to the signal.

Comment: That is curious. In the [Basta](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/basta/about/) project, I use a background process which every 15 seconds sends a signal to the interactive shell, which updates the status line. Thus the time/date shown in the status line updates spontaneously. I'm not seeing programs run from the interactive shell being affected by thesignal, even though that background process runs all the time.  When you send a signal to a positive integer PID, it should go to one process only.  Capture a `strace -f -o logfile ./script` of the whole scenario to see how gnome-calculator is dying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait using `wait`

```
trap 'echo hello' USR1 USR2
gnome-calculator >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $$
until wait; do
    :
done
```

and send the signal like so

```
kill -USR1 123
```

Comment: This still terminates `gnome-calculator`, unfortunately.

Comment: Can't reproduce that behavior here on Ubuntu 22.04. Make sure you send the signal to the shell only, not the process group it belongs.

Comment: To clarify, you're using the PID printed by `echo $$` right?

Comment: Yes. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP99t.png

Comment: That's really weird. I'm on NixOS, I wonder if it has something to do with it.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8sI.jpg You must have broken something.

Comment: Yep, I did something wrong, my bad. I used the `-n` syntax which kills the whole process group apparently. Also thanks for going out of your way to test it on NixOS.